# Karma not load a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

I want test a function using Karma:
This is the structure of my code:

```
WebContent
|
|___js
|   |
|   |__sourceCode.js
|
|___test-resources
    |
    |__myTest.js
```

This is the full content of sourceCode.js :

```js
//ui5bp={};
ui5bp.sourceCode={
    doubleSum:function (a, b) {
        return (a + b) * 2;
    }
}

/*
function doubleSum(a, b) {
    return (a + b) * 2;
}*/
```

and this an extract of my karma config file:

```
...
files: [
      'WebContent/js/sourceCode.js',
      //'WebContent/test-resources/myTest.js'
    ],
...
```

Ok. Now I want run Karma, at the moment without test (in the config file I have commented the test) but I have a problem:

```
ui5bp is not defined
```

instead if I modify `sourceCode` writing directly the function, I don't have problems!

I have organized my code using objects grouping functions and I would like test these funcions by init tests.

Comment: The path of the files shoulnd't be `'WebContent/js/sourceCode.js'` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was wrong to write the Q. 
The path is already right.
This is not the problem..

Comment: Which files do you see loaded in the HTML page on the browser? What do you see when you point the browser to `localhost:9876/base/WebContent/js/sourceCode.js`?

Comment: if I add `ui5bp={};` on top of `sourceCode.js` , the error vanish... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem: I wanted test function already been written without modify their. 
The problem was that loading `sourceCode.js` file without pass through the initialization of my framework (openui5), I not have created the *ui5bp* object...

The solution is create a new file `define.js` with only this content:

```js
//define.js file
var ui5bp={};
```

and import it with the other files using karma config file:

```js
...
files: [
      'WebContent/test-resources/define.js'
      'WebContent/js/sourceCode.js',
      //'WebContent/test-resources/myTest.js'
    ],
...
```

`define.js` is loaded only from Karma tests, and I not use it when I want run my app.